# How to access Array[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Given the following code:

```
List<int> Data = new List<int>();
Data.Add(1);
Data.Add(2);
Array[] tmp = new Array[Data.Count];
tmp[0] = Data.ToString().ToArray();
```

How to access the `Data` array in `tmp[0]`?

I have try `tmp[0,0]` or `tmp[0].Data[0]` but it doesn't work and gives me an error.

simple is can I  add array to array onedimesion? if can how?

Comment: I don't get it, why you use list and then go 'back' to array. Anyway, `Data.ToString()` returns 'System.Collections...' The closest thing to what you want is `tmp[0] = Data[0].ToString().ToArray();` but why not just use `Data[0]`?

Comment: because one time I want to add two array i tmp, sorry if u confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write

```
Array tmp;
tmp = Data.ToArray();
for(int x = 0; x < tmp.Length; x++)
    Console.WriteLine(tmp.GetValue(x));
```

However I recommend to stick at using a strong typed List

Going deeper along this slippery path you could create an Array of Array (oh boy this start to get confusing)

```
// Create an array of two Array
Array[] tmp = new Array[Data.Count];
// First array set to the integer array
tmp[0] = Data.ToArray();
// Second array of strings
tmp[1] = new string[5];

// Set first element of the second array to a string
tmp[1].SetValue("Steve", 0);
```

Again, forget this approach and use more advanced collection classes like

[Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Hashset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: how if I want to add two List in tmp?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your data a a specific position just use

```
Data[Index]
```

if you realy want to use a array you can do

```
int[] array = Data.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Must do like this.

```
List<int> Data = new List<int>();

Data.Add(1);

Data.Add(2);

int[] tmp = Data.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use

```
var array=Data.ToArray();
```

and if you want to add new item in array you might want to resize it first using

```
Array.Resize(ref array, array.Count() + 1);
array[array.Count()]=//your items here..
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding. deleting use `List<T>`:

```
  List<int> Data = new List<int>();

  // Add item after item
  Data.Add(1);
  Data.Add(2);

  // Add whole range of items, e.g. an array
  Data.AddRange(new int[] {3, 4, 5});

  int v = Data[0];
  Data[0] = v + 10;

  Console.Write(String.Join(", ", Data));
```

Finally, when you to have an array

```
  int[] tmp = Data.ToArray();
  // you still can read an item
  int x = tmp[0];
  // and write it
  tmp[0] = x - 10;
```

But remember, you can't do `tmp.Add()` or `tmp.RemoveAt()`